# Assigning a Class to a VC in IB results in black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I am new to coding, however I don't believe this to be a rookie error as it's so simple.

I designed a VC, embedded in a Navigation Controller, everytime I would segue from the 'Welcome' VC to this 'Register' VC the only thing displayed in the simulator would be the nav bar and a black screen. After slowly removing things from the 'RegisterVC' class codefile and eventually deleting this I was finally able to segue to the 'Register' VC and see it exactly how it is in IB. So I created an entirely fresh .swift file for the VC and I shall insert the code here just for clarity:

```
import UIKit

class RegisterViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is an entirely clean codefile, however as soon as I set the Custom Class in the Identity Inspector for this VC the black screen happens. To reiterate **it works perfectly *until* I add the custom class** Also as a note I designed the VC from scratch in `main.storyboard` just to confirm that it was not this either.

I honestly don't know why this is happening and it's driving me nuts, if anyone else has experienced this please let me know and I hope it isn't something glaringly obvious either. I have attached an image of the black screen for reference.

Thanks in advance,
Adam.

[black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zysyk.png)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your `storyboard` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VC should be a subclass of `UIViewController` not a `UINavigationController`. Create a class that is a subclass of `UIViewController` and assign in to your `ViewController`.

Hope this helps.